# MongoDB mapping large set of data

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, mapping, data-retrieval

I'm tasked with (efficiently) mapping/converting a given array of objects to values stored in a MongoDB Collection and have been struggling to find the best way to do so. The document scheme of the collection is as follows:

```
{
  value: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    minLength: 1
  },
  translation: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    minLength: 1
  },
  mapping: {
    type: Map,
    of: String
  }
}
```

An example of a document would be:

```
{
  value: "ex",
  translation: "example",
  mapping: {
    "0":"No examples",
    "1":"One example"
  }
}
{
  value: "sp",
  translation: "sample",
  mapping: {
    "0":"No samples",
    "1":"One sample"
  }
}
```

The input received is an array of objects:

```
[{"name": "ex", "value": "0"}, {"name": "sp", "value": "1"}]
```

What needs to be returned (after mapping) is something similar to:

```
[{"name": "example", "value": "No examples"}, {"name": "sp", "value": "One sample"}]
```

I've thought of a number of ways to achieve this:

1. Create a MongoDB findOne query for each object in the input array and if found map the values to that in the database.
2. Create a single MongoDB query finding all documents needed, looping over the results and map the values in the input array to that found in the documents.
3. Create a MongoDB query that finds all documents needed and also maps values to DB values

Obviously, option 1 isn't that great. I would like some help in determining the best plan of action. For example, is at all possible to create a single MongoDB query that finds all documents AND returns the correct DB value corresponding to the "value" attribute in the input (option 3)?

Or should I use a different approach to the problem?